# XAMP Server Mail To Function

Tags: php, xampp

I want set mail function of Apache Server in php.ini so that it can send emails.
I have already set the mail function as follows

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 SMTP = localhost
 smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = noreply@myserver.com

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g.     c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

But its not working. Can anyone tell me that what correction should I need to do so it can work properly.

Thanks...

Comment: Here is a link for sending using gmail though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP does not come with a SMTP Server therefore you have to install one.

Note the comment "XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury"

[Mercury Win32](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercwin.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using mailtodisk.exe.  You should look in the mailoutput folder.

Note that on my XAMPP installation, mailoutput is **not** where the mailtodisk README file says it will be.  Look in xampp/tmp/mailtodisk.