# XAMPP sendmail not working properly

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail.exe

I'm trying to configure my sendmail to send emails through XAMPP. My local server resides in Windows 7 & I'm using the latest updated sendmail.

I'm configuring this with my gmail account

This is my **php.ini mail function**. My XAMPP is in the **E:** directory:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
sendmail_path = "E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\ -t -i"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "E:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

Instead this is my whole **sendmail.ini**:

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=MYGMAILEMAIL
auth_password=MYPASSWORD

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

;pop3_server=
;pop3_username=
;pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=MYGMAILEMAIL

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

;force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=smtp.gmail.com
```

And this is the php code I'm trying to execute to send the email. But nothing happens:

```
<?php mail("myemail","Works!!","Mail sent from XAMPP"); ?>
```

Is anyone able to give me some help? Thanks in advance and happy holidays!

Comment: I Fixed it by following this in the end! :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.

Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Didn't I achieve that through force_sender ?

Comment: The comment states it doesn't modify the "From: " header: "the "From: " header of the message content". Just remove the semicolon from the ;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost line. The force_sender will overwrite the default postmaster@localhost value