# xampp php send mail

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail.exe

I searched on stackoverflow and google to find how to setup `xampp`, `mercury` and `php` code to send mail with window server 2008 r2.

And with tutorial found out I can send mail by using `Mail::factory` with `smtp.gmail.com`, and also can send mail by using **Mercury** (<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Send mail message</kbd>) with `my_email_address@my_domain_name.com` registered in Mercury. So I try to send mail by using `php` code. But it is sill not working in my case.

Here are my configs:

**C:/xampp/apache/php.ini**

```
sendmail_path = "\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server=my_domain_name.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my_email_address@my_domain_name.com
auth_password=my_password
force_sender=my_email_address@my_domain_name.com
hostname=my_domain_name.com
```

**code php**

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Hello";
$message = "How are you ?";
$from = "my_email_address@my_domain_name.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if($result){
    echo "Mail Sent." . $result;
}
else{
    echo "Failure." . $result;
}
```

I check in `C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log` and get error

```
--- MESSAGE END ---
12/12/31 06:46:04 ** Connecting to my_domain_name.com:25
12/12/31 06:46:06 ** Disconnected.
12/12/31 06:46:06 ** Disconnected.
12/12/31 06:46:06 ** Disconnected.
12/12/31 06:46:06 ** Socket Error # 10061<EOL>Connection refused.
```

where am I wrong ? Would you please here help me ?

Comment: your `debug.log` `Socket Error [..] Connection refused` indicates, that no SMTP server is actually answering on `my_domain_name.com:25` make sure, there is a smtp server up and running and port 25 is not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: @MichelFeldheim Thank you for your answer , I check in my window firewall , SMTP port 25 is allow in Inbound rules , and still not working . How can I know smtp server up and running ?

Answer (score 3):

Most time is the problem the ip of the server. 
Because most provider dont allow traffic from dynamic ips, from servers with no god spf record ...

A solution would be, make a gmail account, and forward all traffic over gmail or an house internal exchange server.
[XAMPP Sendmail using Gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account)

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I can send mail with my gmail account but don't want to use gmail account to send mail. I want to create new account for my domain , something like support@my_domain_name.com to send mail .

Comment: Where do you host your domain? Didt you allready have an email provider? Create there an account and use the smtp login data for you sendmail.ini

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Is this mean I need to buy an email for my domain ? I created an email for my domain ( ex : support@my_domain_name.com ) in Mercury , and succeed send mail from this email address to some yahoo mail by using Mercury ( File->Send mail message ) . So  why I need to buy an email for my domain ? Please explain me , I appreciate.

Comment: I buy a domain name from www.domain.com

Comment: Because it is not possible to run a email server on a Home server. Better use Google als with your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow instructions as mentioned in following link:-

http://system66.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-send-mail-from-localhost-with.html

Comment: thank you for your answer . I've already config like your link above but it was not working