# How to Send mail on localhost using xmapp and wordpress

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail.exe

I have `xmapp` installed on my system and I am using WordPress for my site. Now in WordPress I have used contact form 7 for the mail purpose and when I send mail from this form it give me error i.e. contact with your system administrator bla bla bla...

I have used wp mail `SMTP` for this purpose and configure it with site properly

in my `sendmail.ini` i have set the following :

```
smtp_server=pop.gmail.com 

smtp_port=587 

smtp_ssl=TLS    

;default_domain=localhost 

auth_username= noreply@bllsoft.com    

auth_password= ------- 

hostname=localhost
```

and in my php.ini file i have set the following :

```
;SMTP = 

;smtp_port = 25

; sendmail_from = noreply@bllsoft.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path

sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

all I have do to fix it but not getting the result that I want.

in wamp I have done the same settings and able to send mail from my localhost properly and I am happy with that.

Sometimes in xampp the mail send message comes but no mail received in my inbox, can anyone help me in this case

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @Daya, that is completely and utterly false.  There are a *lot* of things broken about PHP's `mail`, but that isn't one of them.

Comment: Hmm.  Your config is trying to use **`pop.gmail.com`** as an SMTP server.  Shouldn't you be using `smtp.gmail.com`?

Comment: @Charles : I have try lots but fail again and again in that even its working fine with wamp i dont know what happen with xampp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP Sendmail using Gmail account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account)

Comment: Any Expert there yo solve this ?????

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send mail from localhost with wordpress and you want to send it with your gmail account then you can use gmail SMTP mail server.

To simplify thing, you can use this plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Go to its setting page (Email submenu under the Setting ) and choose following options:

```
Mailer: send all wordpress emails via SMTP

SMTP Options:
SMTP Host:smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port:465
Encryption: Yes, use SMTP authentication
Username: **yourfullemail**@gmail.com
Password: **yourgmailpassword**
```

Answer (score 0):

Under `sendmail.ini`, try changing the `smtp_server = pop.gmail.com` to `smtp_server = smtp.gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

On your php.ini file ususally found on 'C:\xampp\php'

Edit [mail function]

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = youremail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

**Step 2**

On your sendmail.ini file ususally found on 'C:\xampp\sendmail'

Edit [sendmail]

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=youremail@gmail.com
auth_password=yourpassword
```

**Step 3**

Restart Apache

**Step 4**

On your gmail account
My Account > Sign-in & security

Switch 'ON' the 'Allow less secure apps'

Answer (score 0):

This is my snippet based on [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) you need first to install [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) and then configure it just need the add the next snippet into your `functions.php`

https://gist.github.com/khalidahmada/74c3ba52e7d179e323b30d97f4847ec6

Please note that you need the configure your rule that checks if turn on local or not by default rule tests the constant `'WP_HOME'` into your `wp-config.php` if contains 'test' or 'local' either that you need to specify your own role rule the function in the snippet it's `isLocal()`