# Php-can i send mail from my home computer using windows7 xampp

Tags: php, email

I have static ip on my home computer.
I am using windows-7 with xampp .
I creat the code for sending mail

```
<?php
   $to = "someone@example.com";
   $subject = "Test mail";
   $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
   $from = "someonelse@example.com";
   $headers = "From:" . $from;
   mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
   echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

but sir mail is not received at destination.
I thinks is it possible to send mail from my home computer using windows7 xampp??
plz answer

Comment: Use gmail (or another) SMTP service.

Here's the details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5374277/570763

Comment: just tested your code, working for me... im using xampp out of the box right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your answer here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c8aa13/send-mail-on-local-host-via-mercury-with-xampp/
Or here https://www.google.ru/search?q=use+mercury+to+send+email