# Send a mail with php

Tags: php, email, sendmail.exe

I have a problem with my php:I want to send a simple mail in php..I using XAMPP
My configure is:
php.ini:
only sendmail and mail.add_x_header is not commented

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 587
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
;smtp port (normally 25)
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=true
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
```

and index.php

```
<?php
$subject="Hi There!!";
$to="nick@yahoo.com";
$body="This is my demo email sent using PHP on XAMPP";
if (mail($to,$subject,$body))
 echo "Mail sent successfully!";
   else
   echo "Mail not sent!";
  ?>
```

It runs without errors but the mail does not come...Where is my error ?pliz help me

Comment: Could you be having a firewall problem? And have you checked your PHP logs ?

Comment: Are you sure you php.ini `sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"` looks good? I suspect you have either an unbalanced quote or some unescaped backslashes! Try `sendmail_path = C:/xampp/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t`

Comment: Give this post a try: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account)

Comment: You've got some weird quoting on the sendmail_path line there...

Comment: I tried eugen but doesn't work..

Comment: I note like this: sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" but also without effect

Comment: My PHP on Windows sends server via SMTP of my ISP. You can probably do that too. No need for a fake `sendmail`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra quotation mark in your sendmail_path setting. Try changing your php.ini file from:

```
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

to

```
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

Also are you doing this on a personal ISP or at work? Your ports might be blocked. Additionally Yahoo could be filtering your email as well. Could try adding headers.

Comment: What headers? Anti-spam headers?