# Xampp php not sending emails

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to get php to send an test email through my xampp, I know I have to configure the php.inc file and the sendmail file to get xampp to send emails.

but even after all this I still can't send emails

heres the modified snippets of code for both the files

php.inc

```
[ mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = {email}@gmail.com

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g.     c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
 ; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

sendmail.ini (I added this at the bottom of the file)

```
    ;new config:
 smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
error_logfile=error.log
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_recipient=
hostname=

auth_username={email}@gmail.com
auth_password={mypass }
 force_sender={email}@gmail.com
```

any ideas why this configurations not working?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't send emails directly from your local machine using xampp or mampp or something.

You need to deploy the script to a server having email gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can send email directly using Mamp but not Xampp. I'm using Mamp right now. If you using windows, try wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by you G-mail account:

Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;

[XAMPP Sendmail using Gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account)