# php mail() is not working in xampp with gmail SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, xampp, sendmail.exe

I just don't know why this is not working!  I've spent more than **4 hours** trying to figure out what is the problem but no luck :(((

here is my setting:

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

---

**sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com
auth_password=MY_GMAIL_PASSWORD
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=
force_recipient=
hostname=
```

---

**mailtest.php**

```
<?php

mail("MY_OTHER_EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com","test subject","test body","From: MY_GMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com");

?>
```

---

**error.log**

```
14-05-29 06:08:59 : Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

---

**debug.log**

```
14-05-29 06:08:56 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
14-05-29 06:08:56 ** To: MY_OTHER_EMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com
14-05-29 06:08:56 ** Subject: test subject
14-05-29 06:08:56 ** From: MY_GMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com
14-05-29 06:08:56 ** 
14-05-29 06:08:56 ** test body
14-05-29 06:08:56 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Connected.
14-05-29 06:08:59 << 220 mx.google.com ESMTP ds6sm39818521wjd.38 - gsmtp<EOL>
14-05-29 06:08:59 >> EHLO SultanHome<EOL>
14-05-29 06:08:59 << 250-mx.google.com at your service, [94.96.120.212]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Authenticating as MY_GMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com
14-05-29 06:08:59 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
14-05-29 06:08:59 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
14-05-29 06:08:59 >> QUIT<EOL>
14-05-29 06:08:59 <<  5  1S†¤Åý  ƒPwq6†­êýIˆ¡Êr¼¡L=;Y       ÿ   #     z0‚v0‚^ :ä^nìó0
    *†H†÷
 0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G20
130910075447Z
140910075447Z0h10   UUS10U
California10U
Mountain View10U

Google Inc10Usmtp.gmail.com0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ©0 ÚÖÖ×Ì®TË¥Ÿ.Jå‚ð·›’
QSÙ^ú{pî¯69~0!ã…°vFH;ARDñãRWAé«{Î»?‘CjÏ)öž3s’~´«WšUm› VäVË—e;¾õðÄ7òù’–c¤bœZßæ’%•Ò¨Ýf'v?P>_ˆ,¨ÌihB?’Ÿs2Ç6>á?ßYCI¨|   ±^2òš¿D…Ÿ$X3~˜ð$Øqõÿ®¢VñöÓ [§º«ÇTÕN–æî¾ÞÖmbc0¿™¢²‘öŸ•Ó½'3xÙ‘<Vpú¥õã%ãÂÿy})´†d¶Ô‚µéâ™ÁJ0½[ £‚A0‚=0U%0++0U0‚smtp.gmail.com0h+\0Z0++0†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0++0†http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0UCMe¸ˆÌ×vø:†)Æð&º0Uÿ0 0U#0€JÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0U 00
+Öy00U)0'0% # !†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
    *†H†÷
 ‚  Þ}@µ†¼-
FÅìY§y¼_x¤_ƒYƒDZš§®×a”àbÑyC¤neï}F–<“y"LÞ¢ûsÍ¨‰S3åK “ÿ)HÚD¨ÿB¦ßŠÀçðüà–¿Õ$<qàqTÐYN`íR±n…ùÿÐ™9™'ýå`²;Ög®ºÞÎìopYWV˜låt²ë’äÎ$×ŠD~1Œ"¡¿p0?Joª ó«Gè®¡˜Q9»X.+(¶ÇÓË<ƒ.¹Ëñ"h–(J«>¯m®Ë¶Æh(,WýàÝ`T•îi•å
pN­mé!óc×ÃaÂeüÐza+î‹!Tåö 0‚0‚ì :i0
    *†H†÷
 0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0
130405151555Z
150404151555Z0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Int
14-05-29 06:08:59 << ernet Authority G20‚"0<CR> *†H†÷<CR> ‚ 0‚
‚ œ*w\ØP‘:£‚àØPH¼‰?ñpˆF~àÅñ‰Î!îZþa
·2D‰ tSOU¤Î‚b•îëY_Æá€Ä^”?¼[H8ôS÷$æû‘éÄÏôS
ôJüŸTÞ}¾ ko‡ÀÐP(0@ÚsQlÿ:<§7Ž½Kë}$Þæùü1qû”Õ`ó.J¯BÒËêÄj²ÌSÝK‹ÈaÍ¨>c+„5ie„ÈÅF"øS•¾ã€JÆ*ìº— Ç9™ ðaz•%ŒNRuâ¶íÊüÎ"j³NÏF——~À±Þ{¯E3Ïº>q·Þô%%Â
5‰ûy‰7Å¯Žri £û0ø0U#0€Àz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0UJÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0Uÿ0ÿ 0Uÿ0:U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/gtglobal.crl0=+10/0-+0†!http://gtglobal-ocsp.geotrust.com0U 00
+Öy0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 6×€'­*›8w³# uX»±~ƒBºrÚØŽ6—àð•;7ýBXþ"Èk½8^Ñ;%në^gvF@ÚÈx
í•fÚŽ†o€¡ºV2•†ÜÜjÊŒ[ö¿Ìo…XÃhQÍýÈ÷y=™5ðV£½àYíOD  £ž8zöFÑO¾Ð@üUþ^<ÚV½–Q{oW*Û¢ª–ÜŒtÂ•¾ðn•ÿð<¬²ÌsûèÆðû3³•;ãÂËhXsÛ¨$b;5
©3½x.Lx]P:Ôî Èp8Ü²ùgú‡@]aÀQkƒkÍ:Êá§xüÊÚ”Ð,=~yÈ P $T3q 0‚}0‚æ »æ0
    *†H†÷
 0N10   UUS10U
Equifax1-0+U$Equifax Secure Certificate Authority0
020521040000Z
180821040000Z0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ÚÌc0ýô#V~[ß<l8äq·x‘Ô¼¡ØLø¨C¶éM!ˆÚX/f9)½x‹8è·j~q¤æÄ`¦°ï€ä‰(ž%Öíƒó­¦‘Ç˜ÉB5­˜F’.OÊñ‡CÁ•W-Pï‰-€zW­òî_kÒ ¹ø5ÙÀF£{rÈ‘¿ÉU+ÍÐ—>œ&dÌßÎƒqÊNæÔÕ{©ÍUÞÈìÒ^8Så\OŒ-þP#6üfæËŽ¤9 ·•9‘þ8.ÑšöM>o¯,`9âú6S9Ô^&+Û=¨½2ë(Rqå«3=á8»6„bœyê0ô_À+èqkäù £ð0í0U#0€Hæhù+Ò²•×GØ# O3˜ŸÔ0UÀz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0Uÿ0ÿ0Uÿ0:U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/secureca.crl0NU G0E0CU  0;09+-https://www.geotrust.com/resources/repository0
    *†H†÷
  vánNK†0²ÏðÇÇq~fîÂíÔ;ÿððÈNÖC8°¹0}ÐUƒ¢jË6œèHf£m¸ÔGþ‹Z\sü®Ù28«—4ª–Òë£I¶»å‘ïƒ6ëVoÊÚ¼scä{>"Ë=í_8tœãPN¡¯˜îaò„?    
14-05-29 06:08:59 <<  F
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Disconnected.
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Disconnected.
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Disconnected.
14-05-29 06:08:59 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

---

***Please Note:***

1. I've read most of the questions and answers here but non of them worked for me!
2. After modification, I've stopped and restarted the Apache Server
3. I've added my GMAIL account in MS outlook 2010 and I'm able to connect, receive, and send emails
4. My XAMPP version is: 1.8.2
5. My PHP version is: PHP 5.4.19 (VC9 X86 32bit thread safe) + PEAR

---

**Your help will be so appreciated...**

Comment: Didn't notice that you were using gmail. If you're using gmail, I've found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost and maybe you should try that. If you're going to use `username@yourdomain.com`, i think it won't work if you're on localhost.

Comment: @GigaByte568 I've tried that but didn't work :(

Comment: [This is a link to a question I just ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41254363/6567932)answered regarding Google's SSL/TLS requirements. Hope it help.