# activation link did not send registered email in php

Tags: php, email, xampp

I have created register and login page.

After registered it shows "the link send to your email please activate".

So i checked my mail, but didn't get any activation link.

I want to know, at first is it possible to send activation link in localhost using php?

Possible means, please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to populate the content with HTML for the linkage. (maybe A tag..)

The following link could help you in making it work:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3478171

Comment: this is not what i need... I want, for example if we do sign up it will send confirmation msg to our correcponding email id right? thats what i need

Comment: yup I guess you implemented all the logic (send/check the activation code), so you will need to check email function on PHP environment.. In other words, you need to configure email server on your local system. (Please note that your email server could not accept the email from the localhost)

Comment: may i know, how to setup  email server?

Comment: how to configure email server on local system?

Comment: @someone help me please..

Comment: 1) set up the email server 2) configure the php to use your own email server when send mail on php
For setting the email server, the following link may help you on ubuntu like system: http://cnedelcu.blogspot.kr/2014/01/how-to-set-up-simple-mail-server-debian-linux.html

Comment: I m using windows, not ubuntu, and one more doubt, this process used only for particular mail id right? not for multiple email right?

Comment: Setting email server doesn't involve the checking process that you mentioned. It is solely about 'Send mail'. For checking the particular mail, I think you should implement your own program.

Comment: if for multiple user access this process, what should i do, please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled PHP yourself, or using XAMPP etc.? In any case, if you correctly configure SMTP you can send email from local.

Check this answer on how to configure XAMPP to send emails using Gmail SMTP server- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5374277/221859

Comment: its only for gamil right? if suppose, user have yahoo mail na what to do?

Comment: Ask Yahoo to provide free SMTP like Gmail does? ;)

Comment: if for multiple user access this process, what should i do, please guide me?

Comment: are you there? thank you

Comment: For smtp configuration, use your own account information. This account is used just for sending email

Comment: may i know how to send email for any user, for example when we sign up in stackoverflow, it will send activation link to our email right?.. thats what i need.. Please guide me. thank you.