# Mail is not going from local server

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

I want to send mail from local server but mail will not send locally. The error is:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

```
<?php
include_once'mail/class.phpmailer.php';
include_once'mail/class.pop3.php';
include_once'mail/class.smtp.php';
class MailSender{
    public static function SendMail($to,$subj,$body,$username){
        $mail=new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        //$mail->Host="mail.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port=587;
        $mail->Username="rahullodhi3636@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password="fdslkfsd";
        $mail->SetFrom('rahullodhi3636@gmail.com','Rahul lodhi');
        $mail->Subject=$subj;
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->AltBody="to view the msg";
        $address=$to;
        $mail->AddAddress($address,$username);
        if(!$mail->Send()){
            return"Mailer Error :".$mail->ErrorInfo;
            }else{
                return"message sent";
                }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something or search for info about the error?

Comment: yes but no correct solution found

Comment: Have you got OpenSSL support enabled within PHP? Also you have defined twice the Host.

Comment: yes i enabled it. in php.ini file

Comment: use phpinfo() to check it

Comment: i have commented of first host  in my real  code please igore it

Comment: what i have to check in phpinfo();

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct password ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP Sendmail using Gmail account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account)

Comment: yes  i am using correct password

Answer (score 2):

The port you should use is `465` (SSL) instead of `587` (TLS).

Also try to use the following Host value:

`$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';`

Comment: i have already try this but its not working