# How to edit XAMPP setting to send email from localhost?

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail

I am trying to send email from localhost XAMPP, I have updated all the required files but still unable to send Email from localhost.
Regards: M.Tahseen ur Rehman.

1. ***php.ini***

   ```
   sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
   ```
2. ***sendmail.ini***

   ```
   auth_username=myemail@gmail.com

   auth_password=mypassword
   ```

**After all these update i have created a PHP file mail.php to send mails but its not delivering any Email.**

```
        include 'connect.php';

        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ; // Subject of your email
        $personal_email= "abc@hotmail.com";


        $message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
        $message .= $_REQUEST['product_type']. "<br>";
        $message .= $_REQUEST['message'];


        $subject_to_sender= "Confirmation";
        $message_to_sender = "Thanks for contacting us";



        $name=          $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=         $_REQUEST['email'];
        $message=           $_REQUEST['message'];
        $product_type=      $_REQUEST['product_type'];
        $address=           $_REQUEST['address'];


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";    



    if (@mail($email, $subject_to_sender, $message_to_sender, $headers))
    {
        mail($personal_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
   // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
        echo 'sent';
        }
```

On Send Button i also send all the Data into Database, and its successfully inserting data into database.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: `if (@mail(...)) { mail(....) }`  is wierd because you would send the email twice if the mail function is working.

Comment: _Google is a maigical thing_  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11020314/2310830